# Type casting from message to packet in Omnetpp

Tags: c++, c, omnet++

How to type cast from cMessage from cPacket in omnetpp?? Because some of the components accepts only cPackets

Please share this info

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you don't. `cPacket` is a derived class of `cMessage` specialized for representing a network message.

You likely have to change your code to work with `cPacket`s instead.

Of course, if you've allocated space for a `cPacket` in this fashion:

```
cMessage* message = new cPacket;
```

Then you can legally cast it down like this: `dynamic_cast<cPacket*>(message)`

Comment: Now am using the 'source' which is generating the cMessages...But most of the modules like tokenbucket meter, classifier, traffic conditioner accepts cPackets so am facing the problem here...Do you know such source which can generate the cpackets instead of CMessage??

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never used this API, so I can't help you with that :/

Comment: Sir am still running with the problem..I have a source, an xyz component(which accepts only packets) and a sink connected serially.. I used this code 'void computer::initialize(){ if (strcmp("source", getName()) == 0)          { cMessage *msg = new cMessage("checkMsg"); send(msg, "out"); } }    void computer::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)                          { send(msg, "out"); }' When I try to simulate this, it says xyz component is unable to cast cMessage into cPacket.I tried your suggestion..But still some problem. Will you please suggest something for this..How to typecast here??